# If there's no credit report at one of the three agencies does this affect decisions by creditors to offer me credit?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-history

This is a very naive question, but I don't know much about this. I asked a [similar question before](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11078/transunion-is-unable-to-locate-credit-report-should-i-be-concerned), but the emphasis was different. I managed to get a credit report through Experian and Equifax (and the reports were pretty nice), but Transunion for some reason can't locate my report. Assuming I have only reports from 2 of these companies, and that for some reason nobody ever bothered to report me to Transunion; does this affect my credit score?

In other words, if I were to want something that needs a good credit score (say a mortgage), will this affect their decision? In particular, is the way they compute the credit score by averaging the credit scores from the three companies (and then it will be considered that I have a 0 or the like from Transunion)?

Thanks,
Nicole.

Answer (score 1):

This is a lender by lender decision.   Some lenders only use one bureau.  Others average all 3.   Some might count your missing report as a 0, and some might average the 2 reports you do have.   There is no one answer to how a lender will interpret getting reports from 2 bureaus and not a third.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a verifiable credit history, that should make no difference. I imagine a lot of people are in your position, and that the lender has seen it before.